# RSA Archer - Calculated field based on date field

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

RSA Archer - I would like to create a calculated field based on a date field that is in the format dd/mm/yy.  The calculated field needs to show both the Quarter and Year of the date field.  Is this possible?

I have tried using Quarter([date field]) and YEAR([Date field]) - is there a way to combine both to get an answer ie 1 2016

Comment: If any of the answers have helped you, you can mark it as a correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QUARTER([Date Field]) &" "& YEAR([Date Field])
```

OR

```
CONCATENATE(QUARTER([Date Field])," ",YEAR([Date Field]))
```

This will give you the result in the format you need.

Hope this helps!